# How can I load bootstrap.css to my rails3 app?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I feel so noob to ask this. 
Now, I have rails app that is working fine with okay appearance.
I wanted to add bootstrap's corner rounded style search box.
So I added

> :class => 'form-search'

and

> :class => 'input-medium search-query'

to form tag.

But it doesn't change :( It's still just square box.
Why it's not changing? and How can I make it just like corner rounded search box just like in official bootstrap website?

Let me give you more information about my configuration. Thanks!!

In Gemfile

> gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'

In assets/javascripts/  I have 'bootstrap.js.coffee'

and application.js starts with

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker
```

In assets/stylesheets/  I have 'bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less'

and application.css starts with

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 *= require jquery.ui.datepicker
 */
```

Comment: add *= require bootstrap_and_overrides to application.css  or you can use individual components try these https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails#using-stylesheets-with-less

Comment: @KapanjadiMomod Thanks!I tried it but it didn't change my search box appearance:( It's so weird

Comment: The easiest way Is to download the compiled version of jus and CSS file and put then into your assets folder. Gem and less stuff really not that matters.

Comment: @Still.Wang Thanks for suggestion. I did add official bootstrap.css and bootstrap-responsive.css to asset folder. But, what the funny thing is, it doesn't do responsive design anymore when I shrink window size. also it doesn't show bootstraps icons anymore either:( I mean something like <i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure you downloaded from the bootstrap project home page.

2nd, all files you need is:

1. bootstrap.css  not min version, cause you are gonna change it later.
2. bootstrap.min.js cause you are unlikly to change it.
3. the two png image files from the img folder you dowloaded.

3rd. put them into your assets folder's relevant folders.

4th. If you wanna make the icons show up. You have to change the icon png file's referring uri inside the bootstrap.css to your current folder structure,for both of them.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the same thing like you.

Think I found the problem, it turns out.

add this to top on your html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

and the form such as

```
<form class="form-search">
  <input type="text" class="input-medium search-query">
  <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
</form>
```

Please let me know if that work

Comment: If someone clould follow the instruction at http://railscasts.com/episodes/328-twitter-bootstrap-basics?view=asciicast , and try to use form-search class, you'd understand what I'm talking about. Style changes but search box:(